Why are so many upvoted questions with upvoted answers being deleted recently?
Just as a small sample, these questions have all been posted in the last few days, and subsequently deleted by the "Community" bot a few hours or days later:

Is an explanation for consciousness even possible? If not, what are we searching for?
Does idealism solve the hard problem of consciousness?
Does the minimum length description principle provide evidence that God is very complex?
Why isn’t quantum entanglement seen as evidence for rather than against determinism?

One could argue about whether these questions are on topic, but none of these questions were closed when they were deleted, and only 2 of the above even have a single close vote.
All of them have multiple answers, one or more of which are upvoted, and most of the questions are upvoted.
I'd hazard a guess that these were posted by duplicate accounts of users who've been suspended, or something like that.
But a lot of effort by plenty of answerers are being deleted as a result, so we should maybe rethink whatever moderation process is happening here.
There's easily been like a dozen or more instances of this happening in the last week.


I'd hazard a guess that these were posted by duplicate accounts of users who've been suspended, or something like that.

You guessed correctly.
It is a certain user who is suspended and continues to post the same content in different guises over and over again.
We're stuck in a dilemma here: Either we merge all these accounts (takes some days, involves work-hours of staff and dealing with the user's denial etc.) or simply pushing some buttons (works instantly, destroys all content).
While I appreciate your concern of work of the community being destroyed/deleted on the way, the decision for me is clear not because of not appreciating the input given as such but because the content has been dealt with in tens or hundreds of questions and answers over the last year alone.
I'd say if anything, I'd like to see this user's posts being identified as duplicates and not being answered in the first place.

I thought I "sensed" a repeated theme and sometimes a similarity of phrasing and "direction" of the questions, from several users.  Who sometimes seemed to work "in rotation"... activity wise.  Even searched a few phrases I thought may have been reused by more than one of the querents... but didn't care enough to dig deep enough to confirm anything.  Nice to know my spidey-senses weren't lying to me.

aren't "IP suspensions" or something or the sort available (assuming they are effective, of course)?

@ac15 works well for fixed IPs but the user has three to four IP-ranges with their provider(s), hence the system fails here.
